# Spring Boot. No proxy when trying to print a non-stored entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

Going from a regular Spring Boot project, I have an entity:

```
@Entity
public class Job {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = EAGER)
  @JoinColumn
  private Config config;

  ...
}
```

toString() is generally formed by Eclipse, to a regular print of the fields is done.
When I am trying to make a basic simulation of the workflow, and doing a:

```
@Service
public class TestService {
   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("test");

   @Transactional
   public void addJob(Job job) {
      logger.info("Adding job {}", job);
   }
   ...
}

@Service
public class Tests {
   @Autowired
   private TestService service;

   @Autowired
   private ConfigDao configDao;

   @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
   public void testJobAdd() {
      Job job = new Job();
      job.setConfig(configDao.findAll().get(0));
      service.addJob(job);
   }
}
```

And this gives a "No session" exception for the @ManyToOne elements of the Job entity.

I do understand that this is far from the usual way of getting things done, but still I wonder why this exception is taking place. The "Config" is delivered at pojo creation, so no "fetch" should even take place.

I can store the object first and then give a fully cached entity back, which will work, but I want to log the Job details before the object reaches JPA.

Stack:

```
019-04-16 15:07:52 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] SpringApplication.reportFailure: Application run failed
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [org.applebase.AutomationAgent.entity.sessionConfig.SessionConfig#1403] - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95)
    at org.applebase.AutomationAgent.entity.sessionConfig.SessionConfig$HibernateProxy$GOSm9GNJ.getName(Unknown Source)
    at org.applebase.AutomationAgent.service.impl.JobServiceImpl.save(JobServiceImpl.java:28)
    at org.applebase.AutomationAgent.service.impl.JobServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$13b2fdc0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at org.applebase.AutomationAgent.service.impl.JobServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae28e0fc.save(<generated>)
    at org.applebase.AutomationAgent.service.impl.SomeTestService.formingAJob(SomeTestService.java:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:261)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:142)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:402)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.running(EventPublishingRunListener.java:105)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.running(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:78)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:332)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Comment: would u please add complete error stacktrace to identify the problem... ?? @AppleBuckler

Comment: sure. Just a sec

Comment: Are there any x-to-many in `Job`?

Comment: There are two. Identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You commented, that there are `@XToMany` relationships in your `Job` entity. Since all -to-many are `Lazy`, it leads to `LazyInitializationException`. Those fields cannot be instantiated within the transaction, since it was passed to the method annotated with `@Transactional` (it was initialized outside of transactional scope). You would have to move `configDao.findAll().get(0)` to the transactional method as a workaround:

```
@Service
public class TestService {

   @Autowired
   private ConfigDao configDao;

   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("test");

   @Transactional
   public void addJob() {
      Job job = configDao.findAll().get(0);
      logger.info("Adding job {}", job);
   }
   ...
}

@Service
public class Tests {
   @Autowired
   private TestService service;

   @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
   public void testJobAdd() {
      Job job = new Job();
      job.setConfig();
      service.addJob(job);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I declared the @X-to-many as eager, and even tried @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE) ? I expected this to help.

Comment: Yes, this should initialize the fields

Comment: I mean that I have already tried this approach, which resulted to the same output.

Comment: Maybe there are grandchildren that are loaded lazily then

Comment: Overlooked this a few times. The two X-to-many relationships lead to regular entities with id and regular Column definitions.

Comment: Are they eagerly fetched?

Comment: Yes. Tried both EAGER and LazyCollectionOption.FALSE

Comment: Hmm, I would have to see the whole code. Does my solution work to you? We're discussing something I didn't describe.

Comment: No. I tried "wrapping" with Transactional every part of it, and still I'm missing something.

Comment: Your first assumption was correct. Started today with a fresh head and found that the session itself was lacking the Cascading and fetching properties. Fixed it and everything started to work as it should have. Thanks!